# Knockout JS: `hasFocus` always has Focus

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

#### Background

I have a single view model, and two models. For each model, I'm attempting to bind a name property to the dom. There are default values for each name, but I want the user to be able to edit these values. Following the Knockout documentation, I went with the [hasFocus](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html)  method. My problem is that, on click, I can edit, but when I click out, the focus does not change, and my array does not update. It looks like my model `editable` property is never set back to `false`. See the corresponding HTML and JS below.

So what am I doing wrong? Here's the checklist I was using (to no avail) for troubleshooting...

1. Ensure that names are observable.
2. Ensure that `editing` is observable.
3. Ensure that my `edit` function sets `editing` to `true`.
4. Ensure that `editing` defaults to `false`
5. Ensure that `<input>` has a `value` binding.
6. Ensure that `<i>` has a `text` binding.
7. Ensure that that event handlers are bound to the value of `editing`

> **JSBin**:  http://jsbin.com/fehoq/117/edit

#### JS

```
function StudentModel(fullName) {
    var _this = this;
    this.fullName = ko.observable(fullName);
    this.editing = ko.observable(false);
    this.edit = function() { 
        _this.editing(true); 
        console.log(_this.editing());
    }; 
    ...
}
```

#### HTML

```
<tbody>
  <!-- ko foreach: students -->
    <tr>
        <td>
          <input data-bind="value: fullName()  + ' ' + ($index() + 1), visible: editing(), hasFocus: editing()"/>
          <i data-bind="visible: !editing(), text: fullName() + ' ' + ($index() + 1), click: edit">&nbsp;</i>
        </td>  
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to bind `hasFocus` against the observable itself, so that the false value can get written back to it.  So, you would want:

`hasFocus: editing` rather than `hasFocus: editing()`

In the latter, the binding only receives the value and has no way to get back to the observable to write to it.

Comment: I see. This technically resolves my issue. Unfortunately, while I can now lose focus, my array still does not update the new value. Any thoughts on that one?

Comment: It is basically the same type of issue.  For `value`, you would need to bind against `fullName` directly, so it can be written against.  If you really need the index as part of the value in the input box (as opposed to in an element outside of it), then you could use a writeable computed. Let me know if you need help with that direction.

Comment: Putting the index elsewhere works for me. I'll have to learn about writable computeds another day ;)